# C# AutoResetEvent not releasing

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, autoresetevent

Using Xamarin.Forms (for iOS) I try to implement the functionality to wait for the user confirmation for the GeoLocation permission to have been set before continuing.

The way I try to achieve this is by making the Thread wait until an event is fired using the `AutoResetEvent`.

The main problem (I believe) is located in the following code:

```
manager.AuthorizationChanged += (object sender, CLAuthorizationChangedEventArgs args) => {

    Console.WriteLine ("Authorization changed to: {0}", args.Status);

    if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (8, 0)) {
        tcs.SetResult (args.Status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedAlways || args.Status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse);
    } else {
        tcs.SetResult (args.Status == CLAuthorizationStatus.Authorized);
    }

    _waitHandle.Set ();
};

manager.Failed += (object sender, Foundation.NSErrorEventArgs e) => {

    Console.WriteLine ("Authorization failed");

    tcs.SetResult (false);

    _waitHandle.Set ();
};

if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (8, 0)) {
    manager.RequestWhenInUseAuthorization ();
}

_waitHandle.WaitOne ();
```

You can find the complete class below:

```
public class LocationManager : ILocationManager
{
    static EventWaitHandle _waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent (false);

    private TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    public LocationManager ()
    {
    }

    public Task<bool> IsGeolocationEnabledAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine (String.Format("Avaible on device: {0}", CLLocationManager.LocationServicesEnabled));
        Console.WriteLine (String.Format("Permission on device: {0}", CLLocationManager.Status));

        if (!CLLocationManager.LocationServicesEnabled) {
            tcs.SetResult (false);
        } else if (CLLocationManager.Status == CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied || CLLocationManager.Status == CLAuthorizationStatus.Restricted) {
            tcs.SetResult (false);
        } else if (CLLocationManager.Status == CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined) {

            Console.WriteLine ("Waiting for authorisation");

            CLLocationManager manager = new CLLocationManager ();

            manager.AuthorizationChanged += (object sender, CLAuthorizationChangedEventArgs args) => {

                Console.WriteLine ("Authorization changed to: {0}", args.Status);

                if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (8, 0)) {
                    tcs.SetResult (args.Status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedAlways || args.Status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse);
                } else {
                    tcs.SetResult (args.Status == CLAuthorizationStatus.Authorized);
                }

                _waitHandle.Set ();
            };

            manager.Failed += (object sender, Foundation.NSErrorEventArgs e) => {

                Console.WriteLine ("Authorization failed");

                tcs.SetResult (false);

                _waitHandle.Set ();
            };

            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (8, 0)) {
                manager.RequestWhenInUseAuthorization ();
            }

            _waitHandle.WaitOne ();

            Console.WriteLine (String.Format ("Auth complete: {0}", tcs.Task.Result));

        } else {
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (8, 0)) {
                tcs.SetResult (CLLocationManager.Status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedAlways || CLLocationManager.Status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse);
            } else {
                tcs.SetResult (CLLocationManager.Status == CLAuthorizationStatus.Authorized);
            }
        }

        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

It works fine except that I can't figure out why the `manager.AuthorizationChanged` or `manager.Failed` event seems to never get fired and thus the Thread is never release when the Status is Undetermined.

Any help or pointers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to know for sure what the problem is. But your code certainly has a glaring design defect in it, and it's my hope that addressing that defect will resolve your problem.

What's the defect? That you are waiting on *anything* at all. You wrote an method that apparently is supposed to represent an asynchronous operation — it has "Async" in the name and returns a `Task<bool>` instead of a `bool` — and then you write the method in such a way that the `Task<bool>` that is returned will always be completed, regardless of which code path is taken.

Why is this so bad? Well, besides the simple fact that it completely fails to take advantage of the asynchronous aspect of the interface you're implementing, it is quite likely that the `CLLocationManager` class you're using expects to be able to run in the same thread in which your `IsGeolocationEnabledAsync()` method is called. Since this method isn't returning until the events are raised and since the events can't be raised until the method returns, you have a deadlock.

IMHO, this is how your class should be implemented:

```
public class LocationManager : ILocationManager
{
    public async Task<bool> IsGeolocationEnabledAsync()
    {
        bool result;

        Console.WriteLine (String.Format("Avaible on device: {0}", CLLocationManager.LocationServicesEnabled));
        Console.WriteLine (String.Format("Permission on device: {0}", CLLocationManager.Status));

        if (!CLLocationManager.LocationServicesEnabled) {
            result = false;
        } else if (CLLocationManager.Status == CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied || CLLocationManager.Status == CLAuthorizationStatus.Restricted) {
            result = false;
        } else if (CLLocationManager.Status == CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined) {
            TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

            Console.WriteLine ("Waiting for authorisation");

            CLLocationManager manager = new CLLocationManager ();

            manager.AuthorizationChanged += (object sender, CLAuthorizationChangedEventArgs args) => {

                Console.WriteLine ("Authorization changed to: {0}", args.Status);

                if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (8, 0)) {
                    tcs.SetResult (args.Status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedAlways || args.Status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse);
                } else {
                    tcs.SetResult (args.Status == CLAuthorizationStatus.Authorized);
                }
            };

            manager.Failed += (object sender, Foundation.NSErrorEventArgs e) => {

                Console.WriteLine ("Authorization failed");

                tcs.SetResult (false);
            };

            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (8, 0)) {
                manager.RequestWhenInUseAuthorization ();
                result = await tcs.Task;
            } else {
                result = false;
            }

            Console.WriteLine (String.Format ("Auth complete: {0}", tcs.Task.Result));

        } else {
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (8, 0)) {
                result = CLLocationManager.Status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedAlways || CLLocationManager.Status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse;
            } else {
                result = CLLocationManager.Status == CLAuthorizationStatus.Authorized;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

I.e. turn the method into an `async` method, don't bother with the `TaskCompletionSource` at all unless you will actually need to wait on anything, and then `await` the result of the `CLLocationManager`'s asynchronous operation, returning its result.

This will allow the method to return immediately even in the case when you are calling `CLLocationManager.RequestWhenInUseAuthorization()`, without changing the semantics for the caller (i.e. it still sees a `Task<bool>` return value and can `await` the result). If the method completes synchronously, the caller won't have to actually wait. If it doesn't, then assuming the caller has been written correctly and it itself is not blocking the thread waiting for the result, the operation will be able to complete normally, setting the completion source's result and letting the code that's waiting on it proceed.

Notes:

- The above assumes that in your platform you have available the `async`/`await` feature. If you do not, it is simple enough to adjust to accommodate; it's basically the same technique as above, except that you would in fact use the `TaskCompletionSource` for all of the branches in the method instead of just the asynchronous one, and then would return the `tcs.Task` value just like you were before. Note that in that case, you would have to call `ContinueWith()` explicitly in your method if you want that last `Console.WriteLine()` to execute in the correct order, i.e. after the operation actually completes.
- Your code also had what appears to be a possible bug. That is, you only call `RequestWhenInUseAuthorization()` conditionally, if the system version is as you expect. This *also* could have caused the behavior you are trying to fix, assuming the `RequestWhenInUseAuthorization()` method is what eventually causes either of those events to be raised. If you don't call the method, then obviously neither event would be raised, and your code would be waiting forever. I moved the `await` into the same `if` clause with the method call itself, and simply set the result to `false` in the `else` clause. I don't have enough context here to know for sure how all that should work; I'm assuming that you have enough familiarity with the API you're using that you can resolve any remaining fine details like that, should my assumptions not have been correct.
- Finally, I want to emphasize that, assuming your problem is in fact that blocking the current thread is what prevents the asynchronous operation your attempting from being able to complete, that removing the wait from this method is necessary but not sufficient. You have to make certain nothing in the call chain is waiting on the returned `Task<bool>` as well or otherwise blocking the thread. I mentioned this above, but it's so critical to ensure, and you didn't provide a complete code example so there's no way *I* can ensure it's the case, so I want to make sure this very important point is not overlooked.

Comment: Yup, the code makes no sense at all - especially, considering that `RequestWhenInUseAuthorization` must be called on a UI thread. 
So he ought to wait (implicitly) for user input on the UI thread; eg. click on allow or cancel.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your time and detailed answer. I learned alot ! One thing I noticed is that the AutoResetEvent is not used anymore. I tried to use this after some googling for ´C# wait for an event to finish´. If you don't mind me asking one more question, does ´result = await tcs.Task;´ in this context do something similar to the AutoResetEvent or should the AutoResetEvent be used in case multiple threads are at play ? (Please notice that I am still a rookie in C#)

Comment: @RVandersteen: _"does `result = await tcs.Task;` in this context do something similar to the AutoResetEvent "_ -- that depends on what you consider "similar". It is similar in the sense that the code _in that method_ is temporarily "paused" until the event is signaled. But it's _very_ different in the sense that `AutoResetEvent` (ARE) does this by causing the _thread_ itself to be "paused", whereas using `await` does not.

Comment: @RVandersteen: Frankly, ARE was never a great way to synchronize threads in .NET -- even before the more modern techniques, there was always the `Monitor` class, which was more efficient. In new code today, concurrent design can almost always be composed in the `async`/`await` idiom and IMHO this is _much_ preferable.

Comment: Awesome, now I really understand why the ARE wasn't a good solution. Once again thank you for enlightning me !